# How do I merge my RSS feeds in "The Old Reader"?

Tags: rss, the-old-reader

I am using "The Old Reader" to keep track of my responses on Stack Exchange.

How can I merge this with another link to also show "votes" or "featured", etc. in the same subscription without having to move from one to another?

Example:
[image: My two subscriptions]
These are my two subscriptions. How do I merge them into one?

Here are the two links I'm using:

For responses: 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/100602/responses

For featured posts: 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured